# Issue in multiple exporting for HighChart with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am facing an issue with exporting a column chart with scroll bar enabled which is not exporting a full chart after a scroll. It works for the first time, but when I scroll to the right or left and then when I export, the export is not happening completely. 
[Here is the sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/fb7gcg7z/)

```js
var processedDataArray = [
{"Series_1_Value":1054237.31,"Series_2_Value":297367.88,"Series_3_Value":955472.31, "other":123450.45, "category":"CATEGORY-1"},
{"Series_1_Value":1914955.84,"Series_2_Value":472603.94,"Series_3_Value":1717425.84,"other":234560.45, "category":"CATEGORY-2"},
{"Series_1_Value":1172527.75,"Series_2_Value":368143.09,"Series_3_Value":1073762.75,"other":345670.45, "category":"CATEGORY-3"},
{"Series_1_Value":908568.43,"Series_2_Value":309490.05,"Series_3_Value":809803.43,"other":789010.45, "category":"CATEGORY-4"},
{"Series_1_Value":8001718.08,"Series_2_Value":5983055.85,"Series_3_Value":7112833.08,"other":890102.45, "category":"CATEGORY-5"},
{"Series_1_Value":1060572.17,"Series_2_Value":317503.11,"Series_3_Value":961807.17,"other":901230.45, "category":"CATEGORY-6"},
{"Series_1_Value":2484203.07,"Series_2_Value":1189924.57,"Series_3_Value":2187908.07,"other":435260.45, "category":"CATEGORY-7"},
{"Series_1_Value":6070895.44,"Series_2_Value":2722014.27,"Series_3_Value":5379540.44,"other":678900.45, "category":"CATEGORY-8"}
];

var series1DataArray = [];
var series2DataArray = [];
var series3DataArray = [];
var series4DataArray = [];
var categories = [];
var seriesNms = ['Series 1', 'Series 2', 'Series 3', 'Other'];
var _colors = ['#2F7ED8', '#915612', '#8BBC21', '#AA86F2', '#9054B6', '#76F0A3', '#A98835', '#09ACB6'];

for (i = 0; i < processedDataArray.length; i++) {
  var dataObject = processedDataArray[i];
  categories.push(dataObject['category']);
  series1DataArray.push({
    name: dataObject['category'],
    y: parseInt(dataObject['Series_1_Value'])
  });
  series2DataArray.push({
    name: dataObject['category'],
    y: parseInt(dataObject['Series_2_Value'])
  });
  series3DataArray.push({
    name: dataObject['category'],
    y: parseInt(dataObject['Series_3_Value'])
  });
  series4DataArray.push({
    name: dataObject['category'],
    y: parseInt(dataObject['other'])
  });
}

$(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      renderTo: 'colChart',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      borderWidth: 2,
      plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)',
      plotBorderColor: '#CCCCCC',
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      zoomType: 'xy',
      width: 960,
      events: {
        load: function() {
          alert('Chart has loaded with exporting option ' + this.options.exporting.enabled + ", min:" + this.xAxis[0].min + ", max:" + this.xAxis[0].max + ", categories.length=" + categories.length);
        }
      }
    },

    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },

    colors: _colors,

    exporting: {
      enabled: true,
      sourceWidth: 960,
      sourceHeight: 400,
      chartOptions: {
        xAxis: [{
          categories: categories,
          max: categories.length - 1
        }],
        scrollbar: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value($)'
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: categories,
      max: categories.length > 5 ? 5 : categories.length - 1
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointPadding: 0.05,
        groupPadding: 0.15
      }
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Column Chart',
      align: 'center'
    },

    series: [{
      name: seriesNms[0],
      data: series1DataArray
    }, {
      name: seriesNms[1],
      data: series2DataArray
    }, {
      name: seriesNms[2],
      data: series3DataArray
    }, {
      name: seriesNms[3],
      data: series4DataArray
    }],
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }); //end of Chart const
}); //end of function...
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
  <title>Highcharts</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="colChart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to resolve the issue?. If you see the pop-up dialog it is not displaying the same "export enabled" boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `min` and `minRange` to your `exporting.chartOptions.xAxis` seems to yield positive results. This does require `max` to still be there, and seemingly it gives varying results if any of those three are missing.

For example ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb7gcg7z/1/)):

```
exporting:{
    enabled: true,
    sourceWidth: 960,
    sourceHeight: 400,
    chartOptions: {
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            min: 0,                           // Added for fix
            minRange: categories.length-1,    // Added for fix
            max: categories.length-1
        }],
        scrollbar:{
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this resolves your issue. As to why, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks.. this option did work. But, it looks like the print stmt inside load() on the main chart defn getting exporting=false after I click the export button. How do I reset all the values back to the original?

Comment: I saw that, but to me it doesn't appear to be the source of the problem. I'm not sure why it occurs though. If `exporting` was in fact `false` I guess the export menu shouldn't be showing?